# Finding number of apps on google play store specific to region

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, google-play

I have a requirement to find number of google play store android apps built in specific region of the world for the given set of keywords.

For example,

```
Input: user Keyword (say "healthy living", "fitness" etc.)  
Search Region: Any region (say "Japan", "Brazil", "England" etc.)  
Output: number of google store android apps
```

I have checked following scrappers:

```
https://github.com/egirault/googleplay-api  
https://github.com/danieliu/play-scraper  
https://github.com/chadrem/market_bot  
https://github.com/thetutlage/Google-Play-Store-API
```

But couldn't get it working. I guess only way is to use selenium webdriver to solve it?

Anyone else have solved it or suggestions? Thanks.